# SwiftUI: How to draw filled and stroked shape?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In UIKit drawing a stroked and filled path/shape is pretty easy.

Eg, the code below draws a red circle that is stroked in blue.

```swift
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        
    let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)

    ctx.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    ctx.setStrokeColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)
        
    let arc = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: rect.width/2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2, clockwise: true)
        
    arc.stroke()
    arc.fill()
}
```

How does one do this with SwiftUI?

Swift UI seems to support:

```swift
Circle().stroke(Color.blue)
// and/or
Circle().fill(Color.red)
```

but not

```swift
Circle().fill(Color.red).stroke(Color.blue) // Value of type 'ShapeView<StrokedShape<Circle>, Color>' has no member 'fill'
// or 
Circle().stroke(Color.blue).fill(Color.red) // Value of type 'ShapeView<Circle, Color>' has no member 'stroke'
```

Am I supposed to just ZStack two circles? That seems a bit silly.

Comment: Check out https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/stroking-and-filling-a-swiftui-shape-at-the-same-time/

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can also use `strokeBorder` and `background` in combination.

### Code:

```
Circle()
    .strokeBorder(Color.blue,lineWidth: 4)
    .background(Circle().foregroundColor(Color.red))
```

### Result:

[image]

Comment: This is probably the simplest solution I've seen. Not sure how I missed strokeBorder in iOS 13. Still think having stroke and fill work together would be a better API. :)

Comment: Very smart! In this way, I can also use ternary condition into view modifier and resolve my huge if-else statement with one line :)

Comment: I would really prefer not to repeat the shape twice in code. This is very inconvenient when I'm using a custom shape that accepts multiple parameters. This can't be the best way to do this.

Comment: @orj agreed. syntax wise i think most devs expect that as well.

Answer (score 59):

**Update** from https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-fill-and-stroke-shapes-at-the-same-time by Paul Hudson:

> In iOS 17 and later, you can fill and stroke shapes at the same time
> just by stacking the modifiers, like this:
>
> ```swift
> Circle()
>     .stroke(.red, lineWidth: 3)
>     .fill(.orange)
>     .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
> ```

**iOS 16** (same source, slightly modified)

You can draw a circle with a stroke border

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .strokeBorder(Color.green,lineWidth: 3)
            .background(Circle().foregroundColor(Color.red))
   }
}
```

[image: circle with stroked border]

Answer (score 20):

My workaround:

```
import SwiftUI

extension Shape {
    /// fills and strokes a shape
    public func fill<S:ShapeStyle>(
        _ fillContent: S, 
        stroke       : StrokeStyle
    ) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            self.fill(fillContent)
            self.stroke(style:stroke)
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // fill gradient
    let gradient = RadialGradient(
        gradient   : Gradient(colors: [.yellow, .red]), 
        center     : UnitPoint(x: 0.25, y: 0.25), 
        startRadius: 0.2, 
        endRadius  : 200
    )
    // stroke line width, dash
    let w: CGFloat   = 6       
    let d: [CGFloat] = [20,10]
    // view body
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Circle()
                // ⭐️ Shape.fill(_:stroke:)
                .fill(Color.red, stroke: StrokeStyle(lineWidth:w, dash:d))
            Circle()
                .fill(gradient, stroke: StrokeStyle(lineWidth:w, dash:d))
        }.padding().frame(height: 300)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: fill and stroke circles]

Answer (score 16):

Seems like it's either `ZStack` or `.overlay` at the moment.

The view hierarchy is almost identical - according to Xcode.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Circle().fill(Color.red)
                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.blue))
            ZStack {
                 Circle().fill(Color.red)
                 Circle().stroke(Color.blue)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

**View hierarchy**:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, at the moment this appears to be the only way. I've provided "Feedback" to Apple that this isn't ideal and think this is an oversight in the API.

Answer (score 8):

Another simpler option just stacking the stroke on top of the fill with the ZStack

```
    ZStack{
        Circle().fill()
            .foregroundColor(.red)
        Circle()
            .strokeBorder(Color.blue, lineWidth: 4)
    }
```

[image: The result is]

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

For future reference, @Imran's solution works, but you also need to account for stroke width in your total frame by padding:

```
struct Foo: View {
    private let lineWidth: CGFloat = 12
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .stroke(Color.purple, lineWidth: self.lineWidth)
        .overlay(
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.yellow)
        )
        .padding(self.lineWidth)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, except that the padding should be half of the lineWidth in order to make the edges touch.

Answer (score 4):

I put the following wrapper together based on the answers above. It makes this a bit more easy and the code a bit more simple to read.

```
struct FillAndStroke<Content:Shape> : View
{
  let fill : Color
  let stroke : Color
  let content : () -> Content

  init(fill : Color, stroke : Color, @ViewBuilder content : @escaping () -> Content)
  {
    self.fill = fill
    self.stroke = stroke
    self.content = content
  }

  var body : some View
  {
    ZStack
    {
      content().fill(self.fill)
      content().stroke(self.stroke)
    }
  }
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
FillAndStroke(fill : Color.red, stroke : Color.yellow)
{
  Circle()
}
```

Hopefully Apple will find a way to support both fill and stroke on a shape in the future.

Answer (score 4):

my 2 cents for stroking and colouring the "flower sample from Apple
(// https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayer) moved to SwiftUI

```
extension Shape {
    public func fill<Shape: ShapeStyle>(
        _ fillContent: Shape,
        strokeColor  : Color,
        lineWidth    : CGFloat

    ) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            self.fill(fillContent)
            self.stroke( strokeColor, lineWidth: lineWidth)

        }
    }
```

in my View:

```
struct CGFlower: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        
        let width = rect.width
        let height = rect.height

        stride(from: 0, to: CGFloat.pi * 2, by: CGFloat.pi / 6).forEach {
            angle in
            var transform  = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
                .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: width / 2, y: height / 2))
            
            let petal = CGPath(ellipseIn: CGRect(x: -20, y: 0, width: 40, height: 100),
                               transform: &transform)
            
            let p = Path(petal)
            path.addPath(p)
        }
        
        return path
        
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        CGFlower()
            .fill( .yellow, strokeColor: .red, lineWidth:  5 )
    }
}
```

img:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If we want to have a circle with `no moved` border effect as we can see doing it by using `ZStack { Circle().fill(), Circle().stroke }`

I prepared something like below:

***First step***

We are creating a new `Shape`

```
struct CircleShape: Shape {
    
    // MARK: - Variables
    var radius: CGFloat
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let centerX: CGFloat = rect.width / 2
        let centerY: CGFloat = rect.height / 2
        var path = Path()
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY), radius: radius, startAngle: Angle(degrees: .zero)
            , endAngle: Angle(degrees: 360), clockwise: true)
        
        return path
    }
}
```

***Second step***

We are creating a new `ButtonStyle`

```
struct LikeButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
        
        // MARK: Constants
        private struct Const {
            static let yHeartOffset: CGFloat = 1
            static let pressedScale: CGFloat = 0.8
            static let borderWidth: CGFloat = 1
        }
        
        // MARK: - Variables
        var radius: CGFloat
        var isSelected: Bool
        
        func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
            ZStack {
                if isSelected {
                    CircleShape(radius: radius)
                        .stroke(Color.red)
                        .animation(.easeOut)
                }
                CircleShape(radius: radius - Const.borderWidth)
                    .fill(Color.white)
                configuration.label
                    .offset(x: .zero, y: Const.yHeartOffset)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? Const.pressedScale : 1.0)
            }
        }
    }
```

***Last step***

We are creating a new `View`

```
struct LikeButtonView: View {
    
    // MARK: - Typealias
    typealias LikeButtonCompletion = (Bool) -> Void
    
    // MARK: - Constants
    private struct Const {
        static let selectedImage = Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
        static let unselectedImage = Image(systemName: "heart")
        static let textMultiplier: CGFloat = 0.57
        static var textSize: CGFloat { 30 * textMultiplier }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Variables
    @State var isSelected: Bool = false
    private var radius: CGFloat = 15.0
    private var completion: LikeButtonCompletion?
    
    init(isSelected: Bool, completion: LikeButtonCompletion? = nil) {
        _isSelected = State(initialValue: isSelected)
        self.completion = completion
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.isSelected.toggle()
                    self.completion?(self.isSelected)
                }
            }, label: {
                setIcon()
                    .font(Font.system(size: Const.textSize))
                
            })
                .buttonStyle(LikeButtonStyle(radius: radius, isSelected: isSelected))
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Private methods
    private func setIcon() -> some View {
        isSelected ? Const.selectedImage : Const.unselectedImage
    }
}
```

***Output (Selected and unselected state):***

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Building on the previous answer by lochiwei...

```
public func fill<S:ShapeStyle>(_ fillContent: S,
                                   opacity: Double,
                                   strokeWidth: CGFloat,
                                   strokeColor: S) -> some View
    {
        ZStack {
            self.fill(fillContent).opacity(opacity)
            self.stroke(strokeColor, lineWidth: strokeWidth)
        }
    }
```

Used on a `Shape` object:

```
struct SelectionIndicator : Shape {
    let parentWidth: CGFloat
    let parentHeight: CGFloat
    let radius: CGFloat
    let sectorAngle: Double


    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path { ... }
}

SelectionIndicator(parentWidth: g.size.width,
                        parentHeight: g.size.height,
                        radius: self.radius + 10,
                        sectorAngle: self.pathNodes[0].sectorAngle.degrees)
                    .fill(Color.yellow, opacity: 0.2, strokeWidth: 3, strokeColor: Color.white)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the extensions I use for filling and stroking a shape. None of the other answers allow full customization of the fill and stroke style.

```swift
extension Shape {
    
    /// Fills and strokes a shape.
    func style<F: ShapeStyle, S: ShapeStyle>(
        fill: F,
        stroke: S,
        strokeStyle: StrokeStyle
    ) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            self.fill(fill)
            self.stroke(stroke, style: strokeStyle)
        }
    }
    
    /// Fills and strokes a shape.
    func style<F: ShapeStyle, S: ShapeStyle>(
        fill: F,
        stroke: S,
        lineWidth: CGFloat = 1
    ) -> some View {
        self.style(
            fill: fill,
            stroke: stroke,
            strokeStyle: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: lineWidth)
        )
    }
    
}

extension InsettableShape {
    
    /// Fills and strokes an insettable shape.
    func style<F: ShapeStyle, S: ShapeStyle>(
        fill: F,
        strokeBorder: S,
        strokeStyle: StrokeStyle
    ) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            self.fill(fill)
            self.strokeBorder(strokeBorder, style: strokeStyle)
        }
    }
    
    /// Fills and strokes an insettable shape.
    func style<F: ShapeStyle, S: ShapeStyle>(
        fill: F,
        strokeBorder: S,
        lineWidth: CGFloat = 1
    ) -> some View {
        self.style(
            fill: fill,
            strokeBorder: strokeBorder,
            strokeStyle: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: lineWidth)
        )
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve "fill and stroke" result. Here are three of them:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let shape = Circle()
        let gradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.orange, .red, .blue, .purple]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
        VStack {
            Text("Most modern way (for simple backgrounds):")
            shape
                .strokeBorder(Color.green,lineWidth: 6)
                .background(gradient, in: shape) // Only `ShapeStyle` as background can be used (iOS15)
            Text("For simple backgrounds:")
            shape
                .strokeBorder(Color.green,lineWidth: 6)
                .background(
                    ZStack { // We are pretty limited with `shape` if we need to keep inside border
                       shape.fill(gradient) // Only `Shape` Views as background
                       shape.fill(.yellow).opacity(0.4) // Another `Shape` view
                       //Image(systemName: "star").resizable() //Try to uncomment and see the star spilling of the border
                    }
                )
            Text("For any content to be clipped:")
            shape
                .strokeBorder(Color.green,lineWidth: 6)
                .background(Image(systemName: "star").resizable()) // Anything
                .clipShape(shape) // clips everything
        }
    }
}
```

Also `ZStack`'ing two shapes (stroked and filled) for some cases is not a bad idea to me.

If you want to use an imperative approach, here is a small Playground example of `Canvas` view. The tradeoff is that you can't attach gestures to shapes and objects drawn on `Canvas`, only to `Canvas` itself.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    let lineWidth: CGFloat = 8
    var body: some View {
        Canvas { context, size in
            let path = Circle().inset(by: lineWidth / 2).path(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
            context.fill(path, with: .color(.cyan))
            context.stroke(path, with: .color(.yellow), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: lineWidth, lineCap: .round, dash: [30,20]))
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 200)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```