# How to hide the overflow of the background colour when adding corner radius in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I want to have a view with rounded corners and a custom background colour, but the latter overflows in the corners, as showed here:

[image: Screenshot of my problem]

This is my code:

```
    var id:Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(name)
                .font(.title2)
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Index numéro " + String(id))
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor.opacity(0.75))
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: UIScreen.width*0.9,
               height: UIScreen.height*0.1,
               alignment: .leading)
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .stroke(Color.accentColor, lineWidth: 3))
        .background(Color.accentColor.opacity(0.1))
    }
```

Thanks in advance, I hope you guys will help me solve this issue!

Comment: Have you tried adding `.clipped()`?

Comment: Here is some info to fix your problem i guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56825294/swiftui-image-clipstobounds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `RoundedRectangle` with `strokeBorder` and then a background of an additional `RoundedRectangle` with a fill modifier. This technique is detailed here: [SwiftUI: How to draw filled and stroked shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786163/swiftui-how-to-draw-filled-and-stroked-shape)

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text(name)
            .font(.title2)
            .bold()
            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
        Text("Index numéro " + String(id))
            .foregroundColor(.accentColor.opacity(0.75))
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    .padding()
    .background(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            .strokeBorder(Color.accentColor, lineWidth: 3)
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).fill(Color.accentColor.opacity(0.3))
            )
    )
    .padding()
}
```

*Note: I've also changed your `.frame` modifier and replaced it with padding, which generally would be a more flexible solution that doesn't rely on measuring the screen size, but it's inconsequential to this answer*

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out.
P.S.: thanks for the .frame modifier tip, I'm still a beginner with SwiftUI!

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace this code:

```
.background(Color.accentColor.opacity(0.1).cornerRadius(20.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 15 there is a `.background()` modifier clipped to shape.

`func background<S, T>(_ style: S, in shape: T, fillStyle: FillStyle = FillStyle()) -> some View where S : ShapeStyle, T : InsettableShape`

Try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("name")
                .font(.title2)
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Index numéro " + "1")
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor.opacity(0.75))
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 200,
               height: 100,
               alignment: .leading)
        
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .stroke(Color.accentColor, lineWidth: 3))
        .background(Color.accentColor.opacity(0.1), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
    }
}
```